# RenderTargetBitmap position issues

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, rendertargetbitmap

### Objective

Take a screenshot of a control (or a set of controls) using `RenderTargetBitmap`.

**Source:**

```
<Grid Height="200" Width="500">
    <!-- Here goes any content, in my case, a Label or a Shape-->
    <Label VerticalAligment="Top" HorizontalAligment="Left" Content="Text">
</Grid>
```

**Expected result:**

[image: Expected]

### Method 1

This one basically uses the `UIElement` as the source of the `RenderTargetBitmap`.

```
public static ImageSource GetRender(this UIElement source)
{
     double actualHeight = source.RenderSize.Height;
     double actualWidth = source.RenderSize.Width;

     var renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Math.Round(actualWidth), 
         (int)Math.Round(actualHeight), 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

     renderTarget.Render(source);
     return renderTarget;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: Method 1 Result]

### Method 2:

Instead of directly setting the `UIElement` as the source of the `RenderTargetBitmap`, I'll use a `VisualBrush`.

```
//Same RenderTargetBitmap...

DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
{
    VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(target);
    ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, new Rect(new Point(), bounds.Size));
}
rtb.Render(dv);
```

**Result:**

This one ignores the position and size of the `Grid` and the `Label` inside:

[image]

What's happening here?

Comment: Could you show how the Grid with the Label is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Modified Method 2

I just needed to get the bounds of the descendant of the `Grid` and render only the needed part.

```
public static ImageSource GetRender(this UIElement source, double dpi)
{
    Rect bounds = VisualTreeHelper.GetDescendantBounds(source);

    var scale = dpi / 96.0;
    var width = (bounds.Width + bounds.X)*scale;
    var height = (bounds.Height + bounds.Y)*scale;

    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = 
        new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Math.Round(width, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 
        (int)Math.Round(height, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), 
        dpi, dpi, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);        

    DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext ctx = dv.RenderOpen())
    {
        VisualBrush vb = new VisualBrush(source);
        ctx.DrawRectangle(vb, null, 
            new Rect(new Point(bounds.X, bounds.Y), new Point(width, height)));
    }

    rtb.Render(dv);
    return (ImageSource)rtb.GetAsFrozen();
}
```

**Result:**

The rendered `Label`/`Shape`:

[image: Rendered]

Merged with another Picture:

[image: Merged]

Comment: You need to de-scale the width and height when you render: `new Rect(new Point(bounds.X, bounds.Y), new Point(width / scale, height / scale)));`.

Answer (score -1):

This is because that RenderTargetBitmap render the visual object based on cordinate of its parent object. Margin of itself, Padding or BorderThickness of its parent will all affect the rendered image. 
To solve this issue, you can simply add a fake parent container:
If the original visual logical tree is like

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas Margin="20" />
</Grid>
```

changed to

```
<Grid>
    <Border Margin="20">
        <Canvas />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Settings for Alignment\Margin should also be moved into parent. Now you will get what you want.